# How can I reference System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt in FSI?

Tags: f#, nuget, fsi

Here is my script:

```ml
#r "nuget: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, 6.17"

open System.Text
open System.Security.Cryptography
open Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

let mutable rsap = RSAParameters()

rsap.Exponent <- Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("todo")
rsap.Modulus <- Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("todo")

let key = RsaSecurityKey(rsap)

printfn $"Key ID: %s{key.KeyId}"
```

It fails with this error:

> .../Scratch.fsx(7,20): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'RSAParameters' is not defined.

This is odd, because the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package is referenced.

How can I use `RSAParameters` with FSI?

---

```bash
$ dotnet --version
7.0.115
```

Comment: It works for me with dotnet version 8.0.101.